# What is the swimming equivalent of the word flight

Tags: nouns

The noun for the phenomenon of flying is flight. What's the equivalent for swimming?

Usage: A bird is capable of flight as a fish is capable of _______

Comment: One word is   *natation*.

Comment: @Clare why not put this as an answer? It may not be a word familiar in everyday use, but it's the kind of thing I was after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent.

The uncountable form is the gerund **"swimming"**, which would be used in your example.

The count noun is **"swim"**, as in **"I went for a swim"**.

The one word **"flight"** serves as both a countable and an uncountable noun.